# Watch a JSON file and see updates live

Tags: macos, bash, json

I'm trying to monitor a JSON file a program uses as logger. The file changes multiple times a second, and I'd like to keep an eye on how the values evolve over time.

What I've tried so far:

- `jq` and `jid` do not reload when a file changes, even using `watch`
- `watch -n 0.1 -d 'cat test.json | python -m json.tool'` can reload the file correctly, but it cannot be queried or scrolled
- Text editors acknowledge the changes, but either require a prompt to take them or reset the scroll position on reload

Comment: `tail -f` doesn't help? You can filter output with sed or other.

Comment: Is it feasible to adjust your program to save a fresh copy every time the JSON file changes? This would only be in ‘debug’ mode,...

Comment: No, JSON updates tens of times a second.